# oci8.so is missing in php modules in Linux Centos 8

Tags: php, linux, oracle, oci8, centos8

I'm having a problem to install oracle instant client in my linux server. Its already 5 days i'm stuck with it. I followed the tutorial but still didn't work.

https://medium.com/@azharnian/cara-install-oci8-php-7-di-centos7-851abbb5d15

https://gist.github.com/Yukibashiri/cebaeaccbe531665a5704b1b34a3498e

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnoci/instant-client.html#GUID-96F664E7-AD1D-4FE4-BCE2-6D9687016A51

I've successfully install apache, php and mariaDB in server. I have no problem running my php and laravel in the server.

But my current problem when I install oracle instant client, i notice that **oci8.so** in /usr/lib64/php/modules is missing. When I run command `pear download pecl/oci8` Error as below.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

How can I installed oci8.so in my php modules ? How can I check my OCI status.

Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Where you setting the library search path, e.g. with `ldconfig` or with `LD_LIBRARY_CONFIG`?  Also on Centos 8 you'll probably need to install the libnsl package - I know you need this on RH8 and OL8.

Comment: @christopher I already install libnsl package. but the same error appear . cannot find oci8.so . . am I missing something ?

Comment: The error message just means you're trying to load the extension but it isn't installed, but it's a warning, PHP runs anyway. Is that really everything you get when you type `pear download pecl/oci8`?

Comment: BTW, what [pear download](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.commands.php) does it "Download a package but not install it".

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález . warning disappear after I download the GPG key oracle. So far the warning is gone. But I don't see any oci8.so in my php modules /usr/lib64/php/modules. Am I missing something here ? I'm stuck at 'sudo pecl install oci8' where the command ask to provide the path to the oracle home directory.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález appreciate if you can look on my next question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125777/provide-the-path-to-the-oracle-home-directory-in-linux-centos-8

Comment: You can try:  https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2020/05/18/Installation-of-Oracle-extensions-for-PHP  (nothing to buld using my repository)

Answer (score 0):

https://linux.uits.uconn.edu/2020/03/06/php-and-oci8-installation-for-rhel8/
This link is a step by step on how to install oci8

```
dnf install oracle-instantclient18.5-basic-18.5.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm oracle-instantclient18.5-devel-18.5.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm oracle-instantclient18.5-sqlplus-18.5.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm
```

```
dnf install libnsl
```

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
```

```
dnf install -y https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm
```

Install PHP and OCI8:

```
dnf module list php
```

```
dnf module enable php:remi-7.4 -y
```

(if you get the following message: “The operation would result in switching of module 'php' stream '7.2' to stream 'remi-7.4’”)

```
dnf module reset php (enter “y”)
```

```
dnf module enable php:remi-7.4 -y
```

```
dnf install -y php php-cli php-common php-fpm php-pear gcc curl-devel php-devel zlib-devel pcre-devel php-pecl-http systemtap-sdt-devel
```

```
export PHP_DTRACE=yes

setenforce 0

 echo "instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib" | pecl install oci8-2.2.0.tgz

 echo extension=oci8.so >> /etc/php.ini

 echo extension=oci8 > /etc/php.d/20-oci8.ini

 systemctl restart php-fpm

 systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: Using remi repository, you don't need to buid the extension, which is available in the repository (php-oci8 package)